# Is this an error message in gdb?

Tags: assembly

I have compiled an .asm file using nasm and ld called mymath.asm.Using the following compilation commands:

nasm -f elf -o mymath.o mymath.asm
ld -melf_i386 -o mymath mymath.o

my code is as follows:

; DESCRIPTION: The following mathematical formula will be implement:
; [((x-y)+z)*p]/[(q)],the variables are : x,y,p,q,and s.(variables are type int)
; CAUTION: q can't equal to zero ( division by zero).
; the variables will be hard coded.
; the code is implemented in multiple steps.

BITS 32

global _start
    section .text
    _start:
        mov     eax,1 ;variable x is being set to the given value.
        mov     ebx,1 ;variable y is being set to the given value
        mov     ecx,1 ;variable z is being set to the given value.
        mov     edx,1 ;variable p is being set to the given value.
        mov     esi,1 ;variable q is being set to the given value.

```
        call implementation

_out:
    mov  ebx, eax          ; storing the contents of eax in ebx
    mov  eax, 0x1          ; indicator 0x1 (sys_exit) is being moved to eax
    int 0x80               ; kernel interuppter is called using 128bit, code 


;Input
; eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi = values for "(eax-ebx+ecx)*edx/esi"
;
;Output
; eax = result of "(eax-ebx+ecx)*edx/esi"

implementation:
        sub eax,ebx            ; eax = eax-ebx, (x-y).
        add eax,ecx        ; eax = eax + ecx (x-y)+z.
        imul edx,eax       ; edx = edx * eax [(x-y)+z]*p.
        mov eax,edx        ; copy content of edx into eax.
        mov edx,0          ; preparing edx for division instruction.
        cmp esi,0          ; comparing esi to 0 (division by zero handling.)
    je _out                ; jump to _out lable.   
        idiv esi           ; (tutorial slide) edx:eax/esi [((x-y)+z)*p]/[(q)].
        ret            ; return.
```

When I try to run it using gdb command:
gdb mymath
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/arsaidim/Desktop/CPSC355/hw3-submission/mymath 
[Inferior 1 (process 4625) exited with code 01]

is [Inferior 1 (process 4625) exited with code 01] indicator of a problem or an error in general?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line after _out.  Does it still give the same message?  If it does not then the message is generated by int 0x80.

Comment: I tried setting different break points even after _out, and that exited with code 01 seems to only happen when I run the code from the beginning.

Comment: other than that the code logically functions well and gives the right results in the right registry locations, I'm worried that, exited with code 01 might be indicator of a problem in my code.